# How to hide a menu button from desktop webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I use the "menu-icon" as a button for `navbar` links for mobile version. I have a problem with desktop version, not sure how to hide the button from it?

```
<div class="drp">  //the all navigation bar from mobile version
    <button id="menu-icon"></button> //links button for mobile version
    <div class="drp-cont">  //that is for navigation links from mobile version
        <nav>
               <ul>
                    <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#footer" class="con">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sh">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>

             </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: try `@media query` of css

Comment: add media query in css and hide the desktop button when the screen size is of mobile size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just assign `display:none;` to the `id="menu-icon"` 
and change the display to block `display:block;`  to the `id="menu-icon"`  in mobile device using Media query like below

```
#menu-icon{
  display:none;
}
@media (min-width:728px) { 
   #menu-icon{
     display:block;
   }
}
```

Comment: always there to help buddy. and thanks to accept my answer. :)